# How to make pages metabox display all hierarchy in menu admin?

Tags: menus, pages, admin-menu, sub-menu

Running WP 3.9.1

I've got lots of pages and sub pages.

When I get to create menu lots of sub pages doesn't display on the right level, but some do?

[This is how the pages metabox is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws88k.jpg)

The pages metabox should display something more like this

---

***EDIT***

Number in screenshot are a bit screwed sorry about that.

The problem is after the first few all the pages are displayed on the same level but they shouldn't.

It should look like this

- Page 1

  - SubPage A of Page 1
  - SubPage B of Page 1

    - SubPage 1 of SubPage B
    - SubPage 2 of SubPage B
    - SubPage 3 of SubPage B
- Page 2

  - SubPage A of Page 2

    - SubPage 1 of SubPage A
    - SubPage 2 of SubPage A
  - SubPage B of Page 2

    - SubPage 1 of SubPage B
    - SubPage 2 of SubPage B

...

---

Any idea what cause this or how to fix it, so i can manage my menu?

Comment: try to deactivate all plugins and return to default theme and check if it solves the problem.

Comment: Just retested deactivating all plugins and activate the default theme, still have the same problem.

Comment: there should be a scroll bar that lets you scroll in the list. maybe it is some problem with your browser.

Comment: I can scroll fine.
Just tested it with chrome, firefox, safari on mac and ie on pc.

Comment: then it is totally not clear what are you asking about

Comment: Edited sorry if this was confusing

Comment: Same problem here, two years later, using wp 4.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a fix.

Seems pagination is breaking the display of the the Pages hierarchy in the metabox.

Here is the fix to disable page pagination in the nav menu metabox

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/18282/18282-disable-nav-menu-pagination.patch

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers propose editing core WordPress files, which is *never* a good idea, as new versions of WordPress will overwrite the changes (among other things).

While the original [Trac ticket #18282](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18282) has been open since July 2011, the issue still exists in WordPress 4.6 — going on 5+ years now.

Fortunately there is a "safe" way of implementing a workaround to change the behavior without hacking WordPress core.

Sergey Biryukov, a core committer, wrote a small feature plugin that changes the Pages metabox behavior and preserves the hierarchy for both post types and taxonomies:

[Preserve Page and Taxonomy Hierarchy on Edit Menus Screen](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/18282/preserve-page-and-taxonomy-hierarchy.php)

The plugin only affects the "View All" tab, not "Most Recent" or "Most Used", but is a much more maintainable and responsible solution than patching core or hacking the files directly.

Comment: Good point! Much better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fix that you can apply in your own theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_meta_box_object', 'disable_pagination_in_menu_meta_box', 9 );

function disable_pagination_in_menu_meta_box($obj) {
  $obj->_default_query = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1
  );
  return $obj;
}
```

**Update:** Needs to be added with priority 9 to work well with the default filter `_wp_nav_menu_meta_box_object`

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation of the solution mentioned above, updated for Wordpress 4.6.1

In the file wp-admin/nav-menu.php edit the function wp_nav_menu_item_post_type_meta_box adding the argument 'nopaging' to the array starting at line 319 as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'offset' => $offset,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
    'post_type' => $post_type_name,
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    'nopaging' => true // add this argument
);
```

This will disable the pagination in the meta box and the pages hierarchy should show correctly, even if you have a long list of pages.

Hope it helps someone!